# How to create an ADO connection to Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, entity-framework-6

What is the protocol for creating an ADO oracle connection?  I downloaded Entity Framework into my project and ODP.net x64.  When I go into the wizard to add a new entity I still can't create an oracle connection.  I must be missing something.

**UPDATE**

Still can't figure it out.  Have Oracle.DataAccess, EntityFramework added to my application using nuget.  Specifically I got the nuget package for ODAC and odp.net.  I have the 32 bit oracle client installed on my machine.  I can TNS ping databases.  Why can't I create entity framework dataObjects?  I am missing something.  What it is I am not certain.

Comment: Did you download the client? The tools integrate into Visual Studio and then you can use the wizards from there. I'd recommend connecting through localhost if you're not familiar with Oracle. The TNS setup can be a bit confusing.

Comment: I have connected to oracle before and set up TNS settigns files, just not through Entity Framework.  I had not installed the client.  I might give that a go next.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html This will get you started. 11g was very painful during my last setup. 12c probably has fixed a lot of the issues. Generally speaking it is just providing the connection and specifying a lot of details in the XML.